# Unordered List Sub Menu Horizontal

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a sub menu of an unordered list horizontal. I have tried loads of things including:

float: left
display: inline

These seem to have been reccommended elsewhere with people facing similar problems. However, I just cannot get my sub menu to be horizontal when the "Sub Menu Button" is hovered over.

As you can tell this is to form the main navigation menu of a website.

My HTML code is here:

```
    <ul id="menu" >
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="sub">
    <a href="#">Sub Menu Button</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Button 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Button 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Button 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Button 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Button 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Button 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Button 7</a></li>
    </ul>
```

My CSS code is here:

```
    #menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.15%;
    background: #201f5f;
    height: 3em;
    list-style: none;
    font-family:arial;
    }

    #menu > li {
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    background:#201f5f;
    }

    #menu > li > a {
    height: 3em;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 3;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    #menu > li > a:hover {
    color: #41A044;
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #menu > li.sub {
    position: relative;
    }

    #menu > li.sub ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000em;
    }

    #menu > li.sub ul li {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto 0.3em auto;
    }

    #menu > li.sub ul li a {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 0.4em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    #menu > li.sub ul li a:hover {
    background: #41A044;
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #menu > li.sub:hover ul {
    top: 3em;
    }

    #menu{
    text-align:center;
    }

    li{
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

I am EXTREMELY new to both HTML and CSS so I do apologize if the code is a mess, however, it does work just as I said I want the sub menu to go horizontal instead of vertical.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ShADm/  Works fine for me in this JSFiddle.  Your code is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your CSS to be like this with fixed widths to have better control of your layout:

See it executed here: http://jsfiddle.net/ShADm/6/

```
#menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.15%;
    background: #201f5f;
    height: 3em;
    list-style: none;
    font-family:arial;
    width: 800px;
    }

    #menu > li {
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    background:#201f5f;
    }

    #menu > li > a {
    height: 3em;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 3;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    #menu > li > a:hover {
    color: #41A044;
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #menu > li.sub {
    position: relative;
    }

    #menu > li.sub ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000em;
    left: -160px;
    width: 803px;
    }


    #menu li.sub ul li a {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 0.4em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    #menu > li.sub ul li a:hover {
    background: #41A044;
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #menu > li.sub:hover ul {
    top: 3em;
    }

    #menu{
    text-align:center;
    }

    li{
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

Here's the affect: http://jsfiddle.net/ShADm/6/

Comment: Thank you, that exactly answers the question. Thanks for the example as well! :D

Comment: However, as you highlighted it is not perfect as a menu. You don't know how to make "Button 1" go under the "Home" button do you? This way I will have more space to play with.

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu li>ul{

position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
}

#menu li:hover>ul{

position:relative;
visibility:visible;
}
```

You need to go out to the `<ul>` nested within the `<li>` to make that inner list go out to the side. You are more so trying to affect the outcome of the `<ul>` and not the list items.

I recently made a menu that can potentially have infinitely nested lists of categories and I built the menu basically like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menu_side"><a href="" name="categories">Categories</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="menu_down"><a href="" name="new">New</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="" name="abc">Abc</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

The way I set it up is that if the category within any parent is an array of categories, it will move out to the side, otherwise it will move down. This is built into the code I use to generate the list on my menu. Like I said, it has the potential to have infinitely nested lists within lists of categories, just like a directory tree. I threw over 5k pre-made categories at this system and it worked no problem after I got it down.

```
ul#menu li ul{

    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000;
    background-color:#004080;
    padding:0;
    }

ul#menu .menu_side ul{

    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
    top:-25px;
    }
ul#menu .menu_side:hover>ul{

    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    position:relative;
    left:100%;
    top:-25px;
    z-index:1;
    }

ul#menu .menu_down ul{

    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;

    }


ul#menu .menu_down:hover>ul{

    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:#6666ff;
    }
ul#menu .menu_side:hover{
    height:25px;
}
```

This might not be the most efficient way to do it, but it gets the job done for me.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comment, however, I am a bit unsure of what you mean. Seems you have hit the nail on the head with what I am now trying to do just I am a bit confused by your explanation, sorry!